# Jquery works in console but not on page on replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, special-characters

I have a string which contains multiple "â" characters, so I made this jquery function to replace them (cannot do it server-side).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('#tab-3').click(function(){
             $('#tab-3').html($('#tab-3').html().replace(/â/g, '•'));
       });

 });
```

Now this code `$('#tab-3').html($('#tab-3').html().replace(/â/g, '•'));` works if I run it in console, but not on page.

I must say that I get the string via curl, and the characters are like so, instead of `&acirc;`

Any ideas? Thanks!

**UPDATE 1:**

tried this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
        alert('mda');
        console.log($('#tab-3').html());
        $('#tab-3').html($('#tab-3').html().replace(/â/g, '•'));
}, 0);
```

Alert works, html() shows the content in console, the last one fails.

I'm starting to think it is the browser that prints the â character, and it may be `&acirc;`

Will try this theory now!

**UPDATE 2**

Not working, tried with `&acirc;` instead of â..

Another interesting thing..if i do:

```
setTimeout(function() {

       console.log($('#tab-3').html().replace(/&acirc;/g, '•'));

 });
```

or with â instead of `&acirc;` it prints the string as it is...only if i run the same code again in browser does it work...

I have no idea on what to do next..

here is a screenshot proving it works in browser (the red text above is the console.log i did in setTimeout function...

[image: Console]

Comment: How exactly do you get the elements with cURL, is ajax involved?

Comment: via post, as an array that contains the string....nothing you can do there

Comment: Make sure your calling replace function after `ajax/content added`

Comment: i tried with $(document).ajaxComplete(function(){}); to no avail...any other ideas?:(

Comment: By the way, console generates NO errors.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle that replicates the problem? If I understand your question I was unable to replicate it on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4U55/5/)

Comment: I cannot create a fiddle, as it is a curl request...and the request is the problem, anyhow, I solved it...kindof. will post answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using `echo iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//ignore',$string);` I had to use `//ignore` because it would generate a notice..But instead of converting it to a bullet, this simply deletes the characters....

Hope this helps anyone. Thank you all for your time!